# The data is not recorded in Excel: r-amount of red, g-amount of green, b-amount of blue, x,y-pixel coordinates, respectively

Tags: python, csv, opencv

It is necessary to create an Excel file 'result.csv' with columns x, y, r, g, b inside the loop. I have create program for gather color characteristic seed image. It read in two for cycles this values. Pixel values don't write in csv file.
Tell me why the append function does not work or should use me other? Give me recommendation about fixed this bug.

Code:

```
import csv
import cv2
import os
from PIL import Image  #Подключим необходимые библиотеки.
image = Image.open("S45-3-4.jpg") #Открываем изображение.
width = image.size[1] #Определяем ширину.
height = image.size[1] #Определяем высоту.
pix = image.load() #Выгружаем значения пикселей.

for x in range(height):
  for y in range(width):
    r, g, b = pix[x, y]
    results = []
    results.append(x, y, r, g, b)
    headers = ['x', 'y', 'r', 'g', 'b']
    with open('result.csv', "w") as file:
      write = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=',')
      writer = csv.writer(headers)
      writer.writerows(results)
```

Compilation error**:**
`E:\DiagonalsLinesColor\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:\DiagonalsLinesColor\main.py`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "E:\DiagonalsLinesColor\main.py", line 14, in <module>`
`results.append(x, y, r, g, b)`
`TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (5 given)`

Process finished with exit code 1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the raised error is that the `result.append(argument)` function updates the list `result` by adding `argument` at the end of the list. The problem is that it only takes 1 argument, but your current code passes 5.

Nevertheless, you probably want to simply store the values `x, y, r, g, b` in a list that is then passed to `writer.writerows()` in the last line. Then, you can write `result = [x, y, r, g, b]` directly.